# Saving simple user-entered of EditText

Tags: android

I'm having some problems in my application programming. I searched for solutions for a long time but I can't find it, so I hope you can help.

Let's say I have built an app that enables the user to save phone numbers by the names of the numbers owners. So, the activity contains two EditeText: one for the person name and one for his number, plus a button to save.

How to make the "app" save the user-intered to a text file or any other thing, with FILE NAME = person name + FILE CONTENT = his number.

I want to add another activity which allow users to search for numbers by the insert name of its owner, and also I don't know how to set this feature.

Comment: Bojan Ilievski thank you for answering < but plz can you give more info and i see this function don't save to a file "with name = the FIRST EditText content " ,true? or can plz give a site or artical talk abuot my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to make the "app" save the user-intered to a text file"or any
>   other thins!" with "FILE NAME = person name + FILE CONTENT = his
>   number "
>
> because i want to add another activity which Allow users to search for
>   numbers by the insert name of its owner

From your description of problem it sounds like a good reason to use `SQLite` database for storing your data.

So nicely from the beginning. I think that your idea with files is not good and efficient. Let's imagine a case if you had milion numbers `>` in this case you will have milion files. Then if you want to read content of file you need to open each to get data and it's not good, isn't? Also design pattern one file = one record(user)

Also searching in second Activity will be "hardcoded". Here you had to go through files and compare their names on the basis of name entered by User.

So **as my recommendation** is to use `SQLite` rather than approach with files. Here writing and reading your data becomes more comfortable, safe and effective. Just create table called User with two columns(name, number) and perform appropriate actions. If you don't know how to start, read this pretty good article:

- [Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function for writing content to a file on the sdcard folder on your phone.

```
public void appendToFile(String content, String name)
    {
       File logFile = new File("sdcard/"+name+".txt");
       if (!logFile.exists())
       {
          try
          {
             logFile.createNewFile();
          }
          catch (IOException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
       try
       {
          //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
          BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
          buf.append(text);
          buf.newLine();
          buf.close();
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Note that you will need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. It's a guide on how to save data in an Android app.

**I would suggest a SQLite database** for this particular task and not saving as files on the file system.